# grep : find bigger string in small string

Tags: linux, shell, grep, regular-expression

I am writing a small shell script to receive an input and match against a text file.

However, the input would be a bigger string than the string in the file, against which I want a match.

User input:

```
abc-de-ef-gh1
```

Text in file:

```
This is test,-de-ef-gh,This is test
```

I want a positive result if I `grep` user-input with existing file.

How can I achieve this? I couldn't do it with grep.

Comment: how about echo "user input" | grep -f pattern_file

Comment: Kamaraj - it doesn't work.

Comment: If the user input and the pattern are as in the question, then the comment of @Kamaraj will work. So your problem is not reproducible. Please give *exact* input and patterns. "It doesn't work" will not help us to help you.

Comment: Apologies as I was unclear. Edited the question.

Comment: In your example, which string is the pattern?

Comment: This question is unclear. I sort-of understand it, but not clearly enough for it to be answerable.  @Novice: Do you want to match a line that contains ```abc-d-ef-gh1```? How about `f-gh`? How about `-gh1`? How about `gh` or `1`?  Describe the processes by which you would answer those questions; i.e., describe the rules that determine whether a string should match a line. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You have a file with patterns.  `grep` can read the patterns with its `-f` option.  If you want to check whether a string, `$input`, matches a pattern in `patterns.txt`, you may do

```
printf '%s\n' "$input" |
if grep -q -f patterns.txt; then
    echo 'matches'
else
    echo 'does not match'
fi
```

This would run `grep` over the contents of the string with the patterns in `patterns.txt`.  In `bash` you could instead use a here-string:

```
if grep -q -f patterns.txt <<<"$input"; then
    echo 'matches'
else
    echo 'does not match'
fi
```

The `-q` stops `grep` from producing output (we're only interested in the exit status).

If the patterns are fixed strings (not regular expressions), use `-F` with `grep` in addition to the other flags (`grep -qF -f ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`, `cut` and `grep`:

```
read -p "Hey user, input something: " $n
printf "Match "
grep -m 1 -q -f <(cut -d, -f2 file) <<< "$n" || printf "not "
printf "found.\n"
```

Notes:

- It's impossible to search for a longer string in a shorter, but this is really about finding whether shorter strings in *file* match a longer string.
- `cut` is used to extract the middle field from *file*
- `grep` searches for that middle field in the user input string.
- `printf` provides some feedback.